# Google Identity Sign in. Redirect after user has signed in

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

I am currently working on using Google's Identity sign in code to setup a custom login on our website. I have followed the documentation from here. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

I have the signing in and the button all working. My question is, am I able to redirect a user after they have successfully signed in? I have tried using "Authorised redirect URIs" in the API manager but have had no luck.

Any help or guidance on this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your own redirect in the callback function. Imagine the code in the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/). What you need to do is extend it like this:

```js
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        postAJAX('/server/sign-in', {id_token: id_token})
        .then(function(user) {
            // The user is now signed in on the server too
            // and the user should now have a session cookie
            // for the whole site. 
            document.location.href = '/dashboard/' + user.username
        })
        
        
      };
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `/server/sign-in` will put `$_POST['id_token']` in the `$_SESSION` superglobal. Is that correct? Do you also switch some sort of authorized boolean in the session?

Comment: Also, I think you might be missing a semicolon at the end of your `postAJAX` function call (third line from the bottom).

Comment: The server-side part is up to you. `$_POST['id_token']` will be there but it's up to you use verify it. Once verified you can set things in your session.